# Angular JS. Call property as string

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

i want to use object in the ng-repeat which has keys as parameters, smth. like this:

```
   'fragment": {
       "name": "test",
       "tl" : {
          "pl" : "Test pl",
          "en" : "Test en"
       }
   }
```

I want to access to my tl by language code in template. 
Can i use smth. like this?

```
{{fragment.tl.{{lang_code}}}}
```

Thanks!

Comment: You could get the value by the property {{fragment.tl[lang_code]}}

Comment: it works! : ) thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with:

```
{{fragment.tl[lang_code]}}
```